# Connecting to a container that is based on gcr.io public datalab image

Tags: google-cloud-datalab, google-container-registry

I am trying to have a simple datalab image running from my private container registry and facing datalab connection issue. Please take a look at steps and let me know if you see any obvious issue.

The steps are:

- Running on MAC machine:

  Dockerfile:

  FROM gcr.io/cloud-datalab/datalab:latest

  RUN apt-get update

  ENTRYPOINT [ "/datalab/run.sh" ]
- Build container using the command (only Dockerfile in folder)

  gcloud container builds submit --tag gcr.io/orielresearch-188115/datalab_orig .
- Running on google cloud shell:
  create a datalab contianer:
  datalab create --image-name datalab_orig datalab-test

**The execution is stuck at:**
*Waiting for Datalab to be reachable at http://localhost:8081/*

**when running with debug flag:**

```
datalab connect datalab-gcsfuse2 --ssh-log-level=debug
```

output the following error:

channel 1: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 1: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 8081 for localhost port 8080, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 42885 to 127.0.0.1 port 8081, nchannels 2
debug1: Connection to port 8081 forwarding to localhost port 8080 requested.

Please let me know if you have any idea how to debug / what is wrong with the above process.
Thanks,
Eila

Comment: As per [this](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/1633) similar issue you need to use the 8080 port instead of 8081. See if that helps you

Comment: Also double-check that the container has the correct permissions by SSHing into the VM and running 'docker pull gcr.io/orielresearch-188115/datalab_orig' to ensure that the VM can pull down the image.

Comment: I have this same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two issues:
1. I created datalab-gcsfuse2 from image that was available on the container registry using

```
$datalab create --image-name docker-name datalab-gcsfuse2
```

by default, the image is searched at gcr.io while my image was saved on us.gcr.io
the way to fix this is

```
$datalab create --image-name us.gcr.io/project-mame/docker-name datalab-gcsfuse2
```

2. permission issue. The default service account for vm is
   XXX-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com. Adding this to the IAM memebers and providing it with relevant permissions (project editor or less) resources. 
   you can read more detailed on the github https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/1928

Good luck,

Eila